# getText() of WebElement in Selenium (JS) fails

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've been encountering an issue with trying to extract plain text from a WebElement using JavaScript selenium-webdriver. I'm currently using MicrosoftEdge browser and driver, everything is set up properly but I can't work out why trying to get values from WebElement is broken in JavaScript Selenium. For example, suppose the following document:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>Hello</p>
        <a href="http://bing.com/maps" class="myClass">Maps</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the subsequent querying (setup ommited for brevity):

```
browser.get("file:///path/to/index.html");
browser.sleep(1000); //Just to be sure...
var ep = browser.findElement(By.linkText("Maps"));
ep.then(elm => console.log(elm.getText()));   //Doesn't work!
ep.then(elm => console.log(elm.getAttribute("innerHtml")));   //Doesn't work!
ep.then(elm => elm.click());  //works
```

Anything that doesn't directly interact with the element (e.g. sendKeys or click), including calls like `isDisplayed()` seem to fail and give some exception trace in the console. I'm using selenium-webdrivier 3.3.0 on Windows 10 with nodejs version 6.10.0.

[API](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/) for convinience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

getText and getAttribute return promises that resolve with the value requested.

```
elm.getText().then(function (text) {
   console.log(text);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Working in my aproache:

```
await teste.driver.findElement({
    css: 'input[name="nameElementExample"]'
  }).getAttribute("value");
```